# python - read file lines and place it in array

Tags: python

I got the following code ,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from twitter import *

OAUTH_TOKEN = 'my oauth token'
OAUTH_SECRET = 'my oauth secret'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'my consumer key'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'my consumer secret'

USERNAME =  "my username"
LIST_NAME = "fud"

def main():

  twitter = Twitter(api_version='1.1', auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY,     CONSUMER_SECRET))
  try:

    # view a users lists
    lists = twitter.lists.list(user=USERNAME)
    # create a list
    create_list = twitter.lists.create(name=LIST_NAME)
    # view list members
    list_members = twitter.lists.members(slug=LIST_NAME, owner_screen_name=USERNAME)
    # add single user to list
    twitter.lists.members.create(owner_screen_name=USERNAME, slug=LIST_NAME, screen_name="microsoft")

    # add multiple users to list 
    twitter.lists.members.create_all(owner_screen_name=USERNAME, slug=LIST_NAME, screen_name="twitter,python")


  except TwitterHTTPError as twerr:
    import zlib
    print twerr, zlib.decompress(twerr.response_data, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS) # gunzip response error info 

main()
```

at this part of the code

```
    twitter.lists.members.create_all(owner_screen_name=USERNAME, slug=LIST_NAME, screen_name="twitter,python")
```

How i do replace the  screen_name="twitter,python"   values with values from a file , like reading  screennames.txt lines and place all values  screen_name="values,values..etc"

please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('screennames.txt') as namefile:
    screennames = ','.join(map(str.rstrip, namefile.readlines()))
```

Comment: I  getting  :

  File "twitter.py", line 28
    SCREENNAMES = ','.join(map(str.rstrip, namefile.readlines()))
              ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block